# When making a request to SQLite , it doesn't work

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hey so im need to select certain things of a database using SQLite, the file is called "example_file" and when i use the following command:
"SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE"  it only responds 
"...>"
 at all (having the file already open).
i have tried different db files and it is the same

Comment: Add a semicolon `;` after your query and tell me what happens.

Comment: oh god. i'm so dumb hahaha . thanks!